# Meta-analysis in R with multiple SNPs

Tags: r, meta-analysis, genetics

I'm conducting a meta-analysis on two genome wide association studies (GWAS), each consisting of 150 SNPs, for which I computed summary statistics for association.
I'm using the R package [meta](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/meta/index.html) and the function `metagen`.
It seems to me that this function is able to combine studies but on single measurement effect (I have 150), one for each study.

For example, I may have 3 SNPs on each study

```
STUDY    SNP    OR    SE
GWAS_A  rs694739    0.6691  0.07588
GWAS_A  rs9858968   0.1091  0.01588
GWAS_A  rs1529267   0.9291  0.02588
GWAS_B  rs694739    0.6128  0.37344
GWAS_B  rs9858968   0.0332  0.27344
GWAS_B  rs1529267   0.3481  0.81284
```

so I would like an output in a table format (e.g., as in [PLINK](http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/)), with 3 rows and the corresponding pooling statistics.
I know I could manage it with `for` loops or by grouping with the `by` function on the summary output of `metagen`,
but I wonder whether there is another R package/function to easily accomplish this.

Comment: I have the same problem and I can't figure out a solution.
I started by doing my meta-analysis in PLINK, but I want the confidence intervals of the meta-analysis, which PLINK does not give.
I then tried metagen() function in the meta package, but I'm struggling to write a loop, because the output is a meta class object, and I don't know how to extract the results. I would be happy with any of these solutions: -A way of getting the CI from PLINK
or
-A way of extracting the results from the meta object to a table. Thanks!

Comment: See @Joana's comment [as a question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/109050/32036)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MetABEL part of GenABEL](http://www.genabel.org/packages/MetABEL) does this. For 150 SNPs, you might find coding the loop yourself quicker than ensuring it's doing exactly what you want. (Neither should take very long)

Comment: GenABEL link is dead, it is removed from CRAN, too.

Answer (score 5):

A quicker option would be to use the built-in meta-analysis option from PLINK:

- old plink site: http://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/metaanal.shtml
- new 1.9 site: https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/postproc#meta_analysis

It is quite straightforward, and no additional coding is needed. You could then use the meta package from R to make forest plots of significant results. My experience with the meta package is that it isn't very practical when doing more than a few meta-analyses.